# Does Sahi handle nested else-if statements?

Tags: automation, automated-tests, sahi

What is the syntax for if-else-if statements in Sahi script? The following failed with a syntax error:

```
function caseSwitch($htype){
    if($htype==22){
        type22();
    }
    else{
       if($htype==5){
            type5();
        }  //I have tried adding a semicolon here and it still fails
    }
    else
    {
        _log("Whoops, Hierarchy Type " + $htype + " has not been automated yet");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a syntax issue.  The solution was provided on the Sahi forum here:

http://sahi.co.in/forums/discussion/comment/16735#Comment_16735